# sudo apt-get install show unmet dependencies

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm learning ubuntu from scratch as I do really like it, and in "hard" mode, only ssh access. I've managed to solve a lot of questions along the path but not this one.

When I was trying to install some package, I got unmet dependencies of that package (no matter which one, I've tried some and all of them show the same issue) and from webmin (package I downloaded, use sudo apt-get install webmin_1.810_all.deb but I did not install yet as it was showing unmet dependencies).

As I do get the webmin unmet dependencies with all packages I try this:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

and it also show the webmin unmet dependencies:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 webmin : Depende: libnet-ssleay-perl pero no está instalado
          Depende: libauthen-pam-perl pero no está instalado
          Depende: libio-pty-perl pero no está instalado
          Depende: apt-show-versions pero no está instalado
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Pruebe de nuevo usando -f.
```

So the question is, what's going on here? why I'm getting this, if the package was not installed? How do I remove this?

EDIT: changed language into english, used the answer proposition of solution and I get this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for administrador:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl
  libnet-ssleay-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed
  apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl
  libnet-ssleay-perl
0 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 427 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,734 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Ok, I know this was caused by webmin unfinished install, so the question then is, how do I uninstall an unfinished installation of webmin, or how do I remove this dependencies if I don't want to install webmin (aka, using the "apt-get -f install")?

Thanks in advance.

PD: this server was restarted several times after the "try" of install webmin. Also, don't know if this is needed info but I'm using ubuntu server 14.04.5

Comment: I'd suggest to install the missing dependencies using Synaptic. I have checked for the dependencies you point at in your message and all of them are in there.

Comment: @user123492  I don't have Synaptic as I'm in ubuntu server, no desktop or GUI, only ssh. Anyway I know how to fix dependencies and install webmin but that is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

If it doesnt work

```
sudo apt-get autoremove <package name>
```

Or
    sudo apt purge

Try this

Comment: This happened with me yesterday. I tried this many commands but unfortunately i did something wrong with ppa instructions and these above instructions also didn't solve my problem.i had to reinstall system :( ...if it works for u then its good

Comment: This works. The first command show me exacly whitch is the problem, and `sudo apt-get autoremove webmin` uninstall the unfinished installation of webmin. Thanks. Also worths to mention that this command it's also usefull for this `grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log`

Comment: Gud :) welcome to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The "universe" repositories were commented out in my */etc/apt/sources.list*

To fix:

Edit and remove the "#" in the front of these lines:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ <distro> universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ <distro> universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ <distro>-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ <distro>-updates universe
```

Then:

```
apt update
apt full-upgrade -y
gdebi <package name> or apt install <package name>
```